# Как защитить проверку на стороне клиента?

Tags: java, android, безопасность, клиент-сервер, криптография

Добрый день!
Есть клиент на андроид. Игра. При наборе определенного количества очков, айдишник клиента отправляется на сервер и заносится в базу. Собственно, все игровые данные хранятся на клиенте. Как защититься от умников, которые поймут какой именно запрос отправляются и будут отправлять его через любой рест-клиент?
Сейчас сервер следит за айпишниками, так же вместе с айди отправляется его хэш+соль, клиент обвусцирован. Но мне кажется что этого не достаточно. 
Как еще можно защититься? И заодно подскажите как надежнее всего можно зашифровать соль, которая хранится на стороне клиента, чтобы ее было максимально сложно вытащить.

Comment: Ни как вы не защититесь.

Comment: Наглядное пособие по такого рода защитам и их преодолению: https://habrahabr.ru/post/339596/

Comment: Усложнить умникам жизнь можно, но защититься полностью - никак. На практике достаточно затруднить вычисление всего алгоритма настолько, чтобы умникам стало лень с вами возиться

Comment: @МаксимВоробьёв пожалуйста, явитесь к нам и разрешите наш спор: под «умниками» вы имеете в виду человека посередине, который решил подделать счёт какого-то стороннего игрока, или самого игрока, который решил накрутить свой собственный счёт?)

Comment: Самого игрока, который захотел попасть в нашу базу не проходя игру, а просто отправив запрос с браузера)

Answer (score 5):

В ответе рядом описывается шифрование и т.п. Надо понимать, что это спасет лишь от самых неумным умников, которые все что умеют это включить снифер.

Главное правило - клиенту верить нельзя. Вы не сможете помешать взять ваш клиент, декомлировать его и собрать новую версию почти такую же как ваша, но где все бонусы увеличены в 10/100/1000 раз (при этом клиент будет точно так же авторизироваться и все шифровать). Так же не сможете помешать игроку поменять значения в памяти или вытащить из памяти сертификат пользуясь рутовских доступом к своему устройству.

Единственное 100% средство это перенести всю логику на сервер (впрочем это тоже не панацея от всяких ботов, реагирующих быстрее человека).

Компромиссный вариант отправлять часть информации на сервер и проводить ее валидацию, например, вы точно знаете что ни один меч не наносит 100000 урона и не один сундук не дает 100000000 золота и каждый кто пришлет такие данные - читер, которого можно забанить. При хорошо настроенных правилах нечестные игроки вычисляются достаточно быстро. При это рекомендуется банить игроков не сразу, а через определенный промежуток времени (несколько  часов, дней или даже недель), чтобы было сложнее вычислить правила по которым сервер определяет жулничество.

Но при реально популярной игре все равно будут попытки так или иначе, но читерить и гарантировано от этого защититься нельзя, можно лишь усложнить написание читов и ботов.

Comment: Вопрос был не о том, как защититься от хаканья клиента, а как предотвратить подмену запросов к серверу

Comment: @Barmaley я не знаю, почему вы интерпретируете вопрос иначе, но я (и многие другие) понял вопрос как вопрос про подмену запросов серверу **игроком**, который решил похакать игрушку и накрутить себе счёт на сервере — это типичная ситуация для большинства онлайн-игр. У игрока есть рут, у игрока есть доступ к оперативке и т.д.

Comment: В вашем ответе нет конкретного рецепта, только общие словы: бла-бла можно вскрыть любую дверь, бла-бла можно взломать любую защиту и т.д. и т.п. При этом напомню, что у ТС совершенно конкретная проблема решенная крайне криво. Грубо говоря он спрашивает, вот в моей машине греется движок, а вы ему: надо было ездить на Тесле, а еще лучше летать самолетом. Неконструктивно, коллега - не находите?

Comment: Неконструктивно с вами спорить, пусть автор и другие пользователи сами решают чей ответ лучше.

Answer (score 3):

Описанная вами ситуация - это типовой *use case*, где должна применяться асимметричная криптография. Делается это так:

1) У сервера есть пара ключей приватный и публичный (на все случаи жизни)

2) Когда игрок регистрируется на сервере, то на стороне клиента генерируется пара приватный и публичный ключи

3) Далее клиент и сервер обмениваются публичными ключами

4) Чтобы клиенту и серверу обмениваться данными им необходимо создать сеансовый ключ по алгоритму:

```
clientSessionKey=sharedKey(clientPrivateKey, serverPublicKey);
serverSessionKey=sharedKey(serverPrivateKey, clientPublicKey);
//при этом по математике асимметричной криптографии
//clientSessionKey==serverSessionKey - иначе ничего не "взлетает"
// sharedKey() - функция которая диктуется конкретной реализацией асимметричной криптографии
```

5) Далее все данные шифруем обычным AES с использованием полученного сеансового ключа.

Схема полностью защищенная от всяких умников и проч. Дальше ее можно модифицировать добавлять соли, выдумывать процедуру ротации сеансовых ключей и проч, но это уже вторично.

**Update**

> И заодно подскажите как надежнее всего можно зашифровать соль, которая хранится на стороне клиента

Если вы шифруете соль, то у вас что-то не так с логикой шифрования. Соль нужна не для того, чтобы ее никто не знал, а для того, чтобы защититься от атаки [радужными таблицами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Максимум, что я бы рекомендовал сделать с солью это положить его в другое отличное от хэша место и плюс немного помутировать ее пусть [даже и Цезарем](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F)

Comment: Всю первую часть ответа можно сжать в "юзай HTTPS"

Comment: И это не защитит от умников, которые вытащат ключи шифрования прямо из оперативной памяти

Comment: даже проще не ключи вытаскивать а просто значение результат в оперативной памяти поменять.

Comment: *вытащить из оперативной памяти* - обожаю таких умников, для этого надо иметь доступ на уровне рута к девайсу игрока, ну то есть это сам игрок очевидно и будет :)

Comment: Вопрос вроде был о том как защищаться от умников, которые будут притворяться игроками, при публичной регистрации, т.е. приложение и учетки у умников есть. Насколько я понял этот ответ скорее о том как организовать авторизацию. Это полезно, но не помешает достойному умнику :).

Comment: ну умник мимо авторизации не проскочит (вернее без авторизации не сможет подменить сеансовый ключ), а раз не проскочит, значит он станет игроком - что и требовалось доказать.

Comment: Вопрос как раз про умников-игроков, которые чтобы выиграть будут подделывать данные.

Comment: это я понял - подскажите мне как они будут подделывать данные в описанной схеме?

Comment: Да, просто игрок на своем девайсе на уровне рута будет иметь все права и сможет вытащить сеансовый ключ и отправить запрос "дай мне миллион золота". Более того можно вообще полностью декомпилировать приложение, добавить свой код и заново его собрать, при этом для сервера приложение будет совершенно обычным.

Comment: Сразу видно писал *Специалист* с большой буквы **С**, не вижу смысла комментировать и вообще пора удалиться из бессмысленной дискуссии.

Comment: @Barmaley ваши комменты выглядят так, будто вы ни разу в жизни не хацкали в играх здоровье, патроны и деньги через ArtMoney

Comment: Это правда, я не малолетный кулхацкер, я таки предпочитаю другим способом зарабатывать на жизнь - пока получается :)